# GWT declarative layout parent porperties

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I've built a stackpanel like this

```
<g:StackPanel ui:field="ticketsPanel">    
  <g:VerticalPanel g:StackPanel-text="Tickets">
   <g:Hyperlink targetHistoryToken='newTickets'>New tickets</g:Hyperlink>
   <g:Hyperlink targetHistoryToken='myTickets'>My tickets</g:Hyperlink>
   <g:Hyperlink targetHistoryToken='allTickets'>All tickets</g:Hyperlink>
  </g:VerticalPanel>
  <g:VerticalPanel>
   <g:Hyperlink>Preferences</g:Hyperlink>
   <g:Hyperlink>My information</g:Hyperlink>
 </g:VerticalPanel>
```

As you can see, there is a `g:StackPanel-text` property on each VerticalPanel that defines the name on the StackPanel. I found this on an example in a forum but can't find any documentation or literature on what is happening here..... Is this some kind of "back reference" to a parent property? Does this mean that I can always use something like `g:ParentClass-randomProperty="test"`?

Any pointer to documentation about this will be really helpful. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`com.google.gwt.uibinder.elementparsers.StackPanelParser`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/uibinder/elementparsers/StackPanelParser.java&q=StackPanelParser%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com) class, especially the `parse(..)` method.

In there the value of the `StackPanel-text` attribute (`ATTRIBUTE_TEXT`) is used to eventually call the [add(Widget, String)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/StackPanel.html#add%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget,%20java.lang.String%29) method (line 49) on the `StackPanel` object (the exact call for the provided snipped is `ticketsPanel.add(f_VerticalPanel1, "Tickets");`).

So basically it is just the header of the added widget.